# User data using ajax requests not saved after a reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm doing a form_for a reviews section nested under a recipes#show page and doing this with ajax requests. I'm getting the ajax POST method as I intended too and it's showing on the page just fine, however the problem is it's not saving to the page after I do a page reload.

Here is my code:

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :html, :js

    def create

        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
        @review = @recipe.reviews.new(reviews_params)
        @review.chef = current_user
        @new_review = Review.new

        if @review.save
            flash[:success] = "Review was saved"
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Review failed to save, please try again"
        end

    end

    private

    def reviews_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:body)
    end

end
```

**recipes_controller.rb**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_recipe_find, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :like]
    before_action :require_user_like, only: [:like]
    before_action :admin_to_recipes, only: [:destroy]
    before_action :require_same_user_to_recipes, expect: [:show, :index, :like]
    before_action :require_same_user_to_recipes, only: [:edit, :update]


    def index
        @recipes = Recipe.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
    end

    def show
        @review = @recipe.reviews.build
    end

    def create
        @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
        @recipe.chef = current_user

        if @recipe.save
            flash[:success] = "Your recipe was created successfully!"
            redirect_to recipes_path
        else
            render :new

        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update

        if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
            flash[:success] = "Your recipe was updated successfully!"
            redirect_to recipes_path
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def new
        @recipe = Recipe.new
    end

    def like
        like = Like.create(like: params[:like], chef: current_user, recipe: @recipe)
        if like.valid?
            flash[:success] = "Your selection was successful"
            redirect_to :back
        else
            flash[:danger] = "You can only like/dislike a recipe once"
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    def destroy
        Recipe.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "The Recipe was deleted successfully"
        redirect_to recipes_path
    end

    private

    def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :summary, :description, :picure, style_ids: [], ingredient_ids: [])
    end

    def require_same_user_to_recipes
        if current_user != @recipe.chef and !current_user.admin?
            flash[:danger] = "You can only edit/update your own recipes"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    def set_recipe_find
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])  
    end

    def admin_to_recipes
        redirect_to recipes_path unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def require_user_like
        if !logged_in?
            flash[:danger] = "You must be logged in"
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end
end
```

**Here is my reviews form partial**

```
<h4> Create a Review </h4>
<div class = "row">
    <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset">
        <%= form_for [@recipe, Review.new], remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_field :body, rows: 10%>
        <%= f.submit "Create Review", class: "btn btn-success" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**and my javascript code:**

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @review.valid? %>
     $('.js-reviews').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@review)) %>");
     $('.new-review').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'reviews/form', locals: { recipe: @recipe, review: @new_review }) %>");
<% else %>
    $('.new-review').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'reviews/form', locals: { recipe: @recipe, review: @review }) %>");
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

**review partial for entries**

```
<div class = "row review-row">
    <div class = "media-left">
        <%= link_to gravatar_for(@recipe.chef, size: 35), chef_path(@recipe.chef) %>
        <small><%= @recipe.chef.name %></small>
    </div>
    <div class ="media-body review-words">
        <h4> <%= @review.body %> </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
```

**section in show.html.erb showing the html rendering the partial**

```
<div class ="row">
    <br>
    <h4 class= "review-heading"> Reviews </h4>
    <hr>
    <div class = 'col-md-12'>
        <div class='js-reviews'>
            <%= render 'reviews/review'%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% if logged_in? %>
<div class='new-review'>
    <%= render 'reviews/form', recipe: @recipe, review: @review %>
</div>
<% else %>
    <p> <%= link_to "Log in", login_path %> or <%= link_to "create an account", register_path %> to create an review! </p>
<% end %>
```

**DB entry**

```
Started POST "/recipes/6/reviews" for ::1 at 2016-06-02 16:08:55 -0400
Processing by ReviewsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "review"=>{"body"=>"review example"}, "commit"=>"Create Review", "recipe_id"=>"6"}
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "recipes"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Chef Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "chefs".* FROM "chefs" WHERE "chefs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (27.3ms)  INSERT INTO "reviews" ("body", "recipe_id", "chef_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "review example"], ["recipe_id", 6], ["chef_id", 6], ["created_at", "2016-06-02 20:08:55.316206"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-02 20:08:55.316206"]]
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
  Chef Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "chefs".* FROM "chefs" WHERE "chefs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Rendered reviews/_review.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered reviews/_form.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered reviews/create.js.erb (30.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 110ms (Views: 73.4ms | ActiveRecord: 29.2ms)
```

Comment: What does it mean "not saving to a _page_" - what part of it? Do you mean data is not shown in the form_for controls after page reload (it won't as you use form for [.. Revew.**new**]), or it's not shown in some other part of the page (not form)? If so, give corresponding part of .erb file which shows review entries and which doesn't show latest entry (or all entries?). Also - is it not showing on the page after reload or not actually saving to DB?

Comment: You also do  def show  @ review = @ recipe.reviews.build   end in recipes controller - why do you need reviews.build (i.e. create new review) here? Do you use that @ review object? Because form_for is for Review.new - and not for @ review. Which also might be a reason why saved review won't be bound to @ recipe object

Comment: data this being the review post is shown on the page after a POST request and the ajax call for this works  but after I reload the page or go back to another page and come back the review I posted would be gone. It's just not showing up on the page after a reload. I'm using the `@recipe.reviews.build` cause if I don't I keeping a encountering a NoMethod error with the line being `<%= @review.body %>`

Comment: give corresponding part of .erb file which shows review entries and which doesn't show latest entry (or all entries?) - not only form as it's not intended to display entries. If you use @review there (as it seems by review.body) - why do you use it and not iterate over @recipe.reviews? Also - review it not showing on the page after reload or not actually saving to DB (what's in the DB - is review getting there)?

Comment: Ok will do, I'll provide the review entry partial, the recipes#show which renders the partial, and a entry in the DB showing that it is being saved. and the review is showing up but after a page reload or exiting the page and coming the back the review entry is gone, but it seem it is getting saved to the DB.